# How to enable HTTPS for EC2 instances without domain names?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have multiple EC2 instances running services that I need to expose over HTTPS. However, I do not want to assign a domain name to each instance as I will have many instances dynamically created and terminated.

I tried using self-signed SSL/TLS certificates to enable HTTPS, but browsers display warnings stating that the certificates are not trusted.

Is there a recommended approach or workaround to enable HTTPS for my EC2 instances without domain names while avoiding browser warnings?

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: Are you just accessing by IP address?

Comment: Yes, I accessing by IP address, but I can also access by Public IPv4 DNS

Comment: TLS works by matching the requested hostname to the name on the certificate. The short answer to your question is: no.

Comment: You can put the servers having services behind an ALB. In target groups, route based on urls to your servers. No domain needed as ALB gives DNS. You can add ACM for HTTPS on ALB to main domain. But need to double check it.

Comment: While it is technically possible to get a SSL cert where the CName is an IP address, it's fairly rare, and will never happen for an EC2 IP address, since you don't own or control the IP address.

Comment: @CloudWanderer 
Is it possible to forward traffic for concrete instance in target group (if there is multiple ec2 instances in tg), or I need to create many target groups with one ec2 instance in each to be able to specify for load balancer witch ec2 instance I want to use?

Comment: Not getting your query. However dropping link for AWS target groups - 
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/application/load-balancer-target-groups.html

Answer (score 1):

Ultimately you can't do what you want directly.  Most (all?) certificate authorities only issue to a particular name.  Pretty much by definition an SSL certificate proves that the site is who they say they are.  An IP address doesn't indicate anything so they won't issue it.

I would change this to have a domain name - they are cheap, especially if you're not too concerned about the [TLD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Top-level_domain).  So the solution I see is:

1. For each EC2 you spin up, use something like [Route53](https://aws.amazon.com/route53/) to give the machine a name and a DNS entry - even if it's a random string of characters or a UUID.  So something like `abcdefg.domainname.tld`.
2. Get a single wildcard certificate (i.e. `*.domainname.tld`) and distribute this to each new EC2 (perhaps via a AMI or as part of your machine setup script).  Assign the new machine the same name as you created in Route53.
3. **Or** when you spin the machine up, script setting up a new SSL cert with [Let's Encrypt](https://letsencrypt.org/) with the same name as the machine you just created.

When you tear down a machine I would remove the entry from Route53 to avoid polluting your DNS.

Again, the IP only route will only work with self-signed certificates and yes, browsers will warn people that this isn't a trusted site.  You're going to have to have that real domain name and cert to get rid of this.

Comment: That sounds like a good idea, but I need to access ec2 instance after +- 3 minutes from creation. 
That means that routes in route53 do not need to be propagated in this 3 minutes.